# Time series plot by grouping on a column and row count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one DataFrame which has two values.

The index is datetime and the second column is class_label

I want to re-sample this DataFrame by grouping by class_label and counting rows.

```
datetime            class_label
01-01-2020 00:00    1
01-01-2020 00:00    2
01-01-2020 00:00    2
01-02-2020 00:00    2
01-02-2020 00:00    2
01-03-2020 00:00    1
01-04-2020 00:00    1
```

Is it possible to re-sample by day and show count of labels?

```
datetime            class_label   count
01-01-2020 00:00    1             1
01-01-2020 00:00    2             2
01-02-2020 00:00    2             2
01-03-2020 00:00    1             1
01-04-2020 00:00    1             1
```

Comment: groupby with first and count

Answer (score 1):

It seems as you wish to group by both `datetime` and `class_label` and count the number of observations per group.

You can use `.size()` or `.value_counts()` since Pandas 1.1.0

```py
from random import randrange
from datetime import timedelta, date
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def random_date(start, end):
    delta = end - start
    int_delta = (delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60) + delta.seconds
    random_second = randrange(int_delta)
    return start + timedelta(seconds=random_second)

n = 100
start = date(2020, 1, 1)
end = date(2020, 1, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": [random_date(start, end) for _ in range(n)], "class_label": [np.random.randint(1, 3) for _ in range(n)]})

# using .size()
df.groupby(['datetime', 'class_label'], as_index=False).size().rename(columns={"size": "count"}).sort_values(['datetime', 'class_label'])

# using .value_counts()
df.value_counts().to_frame("counts").sort_values(['datetime', 'class_label']).reset_index()
```